# problem with publish date not always appearing

Tags: publish

I have this problem where the publish date sometimes appears and sometimes it does not.

I am using ACF relationship field to find the story and then bring it to my front page.

`<?php the_date(); ?>`

If I open the story and re-publish it with a new publish date it works.

http://www.thenewshouse.com

[image]

Answer (score 3):

From [the `the_date()` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_date/):

> **Will only output the date if the current post’s date is different from the previous one output.**
>
> i.e. Only one date listing will show per day worth of posts shown in the loop, even if the function is called several times for each post.

[Emphasis mine]

You're almost certainly looking for [`get_the_date()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_date/), which you would use like this:

```
<?php echo get_the_date(); ?>
```